# Show/hide unordered list with JQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menuLinks').on('click', function() { $('#linkdrop').toggle(); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<header>
   <nav>
<div>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
  <li><a class='dropdown-button white-text' id="menuLinks"><i class="material-icons left">&#xE5D2;</i>Links</a>
    <ul id="linkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test2.html">Test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test3.html">Test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
```

I have the following `UL` that has several `<li>` entries. What i want to do is whenever an `<li>` entry is clicked, to show `<ul>` under it. My html is below:

```
 <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
       <li><a class='dropdown-button white-text' id="menuLinks"><i class="material-icons left">&#xE5D2;</i>Links</a>
                <ul id="linkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                        <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/test2.html">Test2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/test3.html">Test3</a></li>
                 </ul>   
          </li>                                 
 </ul>
```

I tried using the following JQuery but it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#menuLinks').click(
                function(){
                    if (! $('#linkdrop').hasClass('open')){
                            $('#linkdrop').addClass('open');
                        } else {
                            $('#linkdrop').removeClass('open');
                        }
                }

            );
    });
```

I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#menuLinks').click(
                function(){
                    $('#linkdrop').toggle();
                }

            );
    });
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only direct child elements `ul` is allowed to have is `li`.

Comment: Thanks. i changed it but results is still the same

Comment: I just turned your code into a snippet. It works.

Comment: which jquery version? in jQuery 3 there you must use `on('click', ...`

Comment: Now there is really no question left, please consider deleting it. Your code was working from the beginning, only it was invalid HTML (but still it worked).

Comment: @connexo, actually it does not work. I had JQuery version 1.9.1 before, then I switched to 3.2.1. Perhaps Sysix suggestion will work. let me try

Comment: I changed it as per Sysix suggestion but still no luck

Comment: **It does work**. Check you own fiddle which now loads jQuery 3.2.1 and uses `on('click', function() {})` instead of `click(function() {})`. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-button').on('click', function() {
    var toggle = $(this);
    $('#'+toggle.data('toggle')).toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
.dropdown-button + * {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="dropdown-button white-text" data-toggle="my-list1">Links</a>
    <ul id="my-list1">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test2.html">Test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test3.html">Test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position your inner `ul` inside `li` and use `toggle()` to show/hide the inner `ul`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-mobile > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
  <li><a class='dropdown-button white-text' id="menuLinks"><i class="material-icons left">&#xE5D2;</i>Links</a>
    <ul id="linkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test2.html">Test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test3.html">Test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:-**

`$(this).next().toggle();` will also work in your case

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-mobile > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
  <li><a class='dropdown-button white-text' id="menuLinks"><i class="material-icons left">&#xE5D2;</i>Links</a>
    <ul id="linkdrop" class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test2.html">Test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test3.html">Test3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not work for me. It seems to get stuck on this part `$(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();`

Comment: see the other method I updated. Both of them works fine in demo

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue - materialize css was interfering with my code somehow. As soon as I removed a reference to materialize css the dropdown started working